# Android ARM Program Crashes when Class Destructor Involked Immediately After Constructing

Tags: android, c++, crash, alignment, native

I have a large class with many methods and data items.  When run on `Windows` or `Linux`, I have no problem.  Purify on `Windows` does not report any problems.  But on `Android` (ARM) the program crashes with these simple lines of code:

```
CDrawGL *pDrawGL = new CDrawGL; // this success..  
delete pDrawGL; // crashes here..
```

CDrawGL.h & CDrawGL.cpp are located in another file.

I included the class CDrawGL header and methods directly in this file, creating a new class CDrawNewGL and this code does not crash:

```
CDrawNewGL *pDrawGL = new CDrawNewGL; // this success..  
delete pDrawNewGL; // as does this..
```

The constructor does not invoke any additional methods but simple initializes a few of the simple (no arrays) variables.  The destructor tests simple variables to see if anything needs to be "delete'd" (it does not). The class does contain std::vector<< double*>> and std::vector<< float>>, neither of which are accessed.

Has anyone else run into this kind of crash?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

If I simply "include" both the header and body of the class in the main code, the simple construct then destruct works (but fails later in the program).  There must be something throwing off the alignment.

```
#include "CDrawGL.h"  
#include "CDrawGL.cpp"  // <<-- added this  

..main program..

CDrawGL *pDrawGL = new CDrawGL;  // this works..  
delete pDrawGL;  // this now works.. 
pDrawGL = new CDrawGL;  

....

pDrawGL->Draw();  // now crashes (fails) down in library
```

Comment: In the updated code sample you're invoking `Draw` on a stale pointer so obviously it won't work. Otherwise one common cause for segfaults between x86 and arm would be that x86 allows unaligned memory access while arm doesn't. But it doesn't seem to be the case here. Heap corruption earlier in the program is also a common reason for "mysterious" crashes in seemingly innocent places.

Comment: Although it was not listed, I did construct a new CDrawGL before the call to the Draw method.  I have edited to post to reflect this.

Comment: I have located the memory corruption culprit. If you use the include from iGLU-1.0.0 (SGI OpenGL code that implements tessellation) in a C++ module it states the tessellation object is a class, when in fact it is a structure.  In ARM when you have a pointer to a class, the class identifier (and possible count) storage is generated inline along with storage for the pointer.  The difference in ARM between a pointer to a structure and a pointer to a class led to a misalignment in my C vs C++ code segments.